# The driving force vs Motivation

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-meaning

What is the difference between **The driving force** vs **Motivation** ?

Comment: Can you give some examples of where you have seen them used and explain further your doubts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Motivation** is a person's reason for acting in a certain way, or their enthusiasm for doing so.

A **driving force** is what it says - a strong force causing something to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In general, they are virtually synonymous.

In use, 'driving force' is probably somewhat stronger than 'motivation'.